# How to create Zip Code field in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I'm creating an app that has Zip Code field by having two `textField` objects. Like this,

[image]

Now I want my first `textField` allow me to enter 5 characters after that control goes to second `textField`. In the second text field, I'm able to enter only 4 characters, after that it will not accept any characters.

I have tried this code

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
if (textField == zipCode1TV) {
        txtFieldSelected = @"zipCode1TV";
    } else if(textField == zipCode2TV){
        txtFieldSelected = @"zipCode2TV";
    }
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    if ([txtFieldSelected isEqual: @"zipCode1TV"]) {
        if (zipCode1TV.text.length>4) {
            [zipCode2TV becomeFirstResponder];
        }
    }
    if ([txtFieldSelected isEqual: @"zipCode2TV"]) {
        int maxChar = 4;
        NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        return (newLength <= maxChar);
    }
    return YES;
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    if ([txtFieldSelected isEqual: @"zipCode2TV"] ||[txtFieldSelected isEqual: @"zipCode2TV"]) {
        zipCode =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",zipCode1TV.text,zipCode2TV.text];
        NSLog(@"%@",zipCode);
    }
}
```

Using this code I have solved some of my problems, but I am not able to retype in the first `textField` and my string `zipCode` does not return the actual value; it skips one value when the control goes from the first `textField` to second `textField`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is within your question use this code which yours but i have modified it,

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
if (textField == zipCode1TV) {
        txtFieldSelected = @"zipCode1TV";
    } else if(textField == zipCode2TV){
        txtFieldSelected = @"zipCode2TV";
    }
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    if ([txtFieldSelected isEqual: @"zipCode1TV"]) {
        //here set the maximum character length and transfer control when newLength exceed maxChar
         int maxChar = 5;
        NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        if (newLength >5) {
            zipCode2TV.text = string;
            [zipCode2TV becomeFirstResponder];
        }
        return (newLength <= maxChar);
    }
    if ([txtFieldSelected isEqual: @"zipCode2TV"]) {
        int maxChar = 4;
        NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
        return (newLength <= maxChar);
    }
    return YES;
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    if ([txtFieldSelected isEqual: @"zipCode2TV"] ||[txtFieldSelected isEqual: @"zipCode2TV"]) {
        zipCode =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",zipCode1TV.text,zipCode2TV.text];
        NSLog(@"%@",zipCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: At least make some attempt to explain what you changed.

Comment: @WolfLink I have added comment at 9th line. i think you have missed that